# I am receiving an error on Map view android java

Tags: java, android, google-maps

hope you're all safe

In this part of the project I am following this code to create a map view that shows a specific location however I am getting an error.

This right here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".activities.PreRegister">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.039" />

    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thie is the fragment I am using to display the location

```
package com.example.toimon.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.toimon.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class FragmentBeforeBrowse extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{
    private Button sensor_btn, man_btn;
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    MapFragment mapFragment;

    public static FragmentBeforeBrowse fragmentBeforeBrowse() {
        FragmentBeforeBrowse fragment = new FragmentBeforeBrowse();
        return fragment;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_before_browse, null, false);


        man_btn =view.findViewById(R.id.man_btn);
        sensor_btn =view.findViewById(R.id.sensor_btn);

        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

 return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap gMap) {
        googleMap = gMap;
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        try {
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } catch (SecurityException se) {

        }

        //Edit the following as per you needs
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        //

        LatLng placeLocation = new LatLng(3.5703335945608576, 103.42567603992448); //Make them global
        Marker placeMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(placeLocation)
                .title("UMP Faculty of Computer"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(placeLocation));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 1000, null);
    }




}
```

And finally this is the error

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.p.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204714067@20.47.14 (100408-0):6)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.f.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204714067@20.47.14 (100408-0):1)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204714067@20.47.14 (100408-0):24)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204714067@20.47.14 (100408-0):2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.g.aX(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204714067@20.47.14 (100408-0):22)
        at ds.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@204714067@20.47.14 (100408-0):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:675)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zza(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.zzc(Unknown Source:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zzd(Unknown Source:12)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:18)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onInflate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:20)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source:21)
        at android.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1443)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3559)
        at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:103)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6445)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:337)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.example.toimon.fragments.FragmentBeforeBrowse.onCreateView(FragmentBeforeBrowse.java:38)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:292)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1227)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1382)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1525)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2316)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2103)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2058)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1960)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:418)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
```

The line in which the error occurs is this

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_before_browse, null, false);
```

Thanks to the comment I made changes to the manifest file and build.gradle, however I still get a blank map with nothing showing in it

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned your API key in Manifest file

Comment: OH I see, could you tell me the api key for maps ? it should like this right 

<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
   android:value= "    " />

Comment: You need to activate it in google developers platform and there you get your API key [here] (https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/get-api-key)

Comment: Thank you, however the map currently appears empty, no more error. may you know why?

Comment: use this `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` instead of  `fragment` to load the map.

Comment: Check implementation tutorial on Google Maps API page and try it. But that is subject for another matter, if your problem has been solved mark correct answer and post new question.